# getFocusAreas() and getMaxNumFocusAreas() cause nullpointerexception

Tags: android, camera, nullpointerexception

I have a custom camera app, and I'm attempting to set it up so users can touch the screen and have the camera focus where they touch.

The problem I'm running into is that when I run the if-statement `if(camParam.getMaxNumFocusAreas()>0){...}` It encounters a null pointer exception.

I tried logging the output first, with 
`Log.d(TAG, "max focus areas: "+camParam.getMaxNumFocusAreas());`
in case it was just freaking out about having it be 0 for some reason, but that just made it have the null pointer exception on that line.

Anybody know why this might be happening?

In case I'm blind and just not seeing what it's saying, here's the code causing the exception:

```
               Camera.Area area = new Camera.Area(new Rect(-500, -500, 500,500), 0);
                ArrayList<Camera.Area> listArea = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>();
                listArea.add(area);
                Log.d(TAG, "max focus areas: "+camParam.getMaxNumFocusAreas());
                if(camParam.getMaxNumFocusAreas()>0){
                    camParam.setFocusAreas(listArea);
                }
                Preview.camera.setParameters(camParam);
```

and the exception in my stacktrace:

```
05-23 07:39:52.023    9780-9780/com.braindudecreations.tangets E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
05-23 07:39:52.023    9780-9780/com.braindudecreations.tangets E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
05-23 07:39:52.023    9780-9780/com.braindudecreations.tangets E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.braindudecreations.tangets.CameraDemo.onTouchEvent(CameraDemo.java:611)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2413)
        at com.braindudecreations.tangets.CameraDemo.dispatchTouchEvent(CameraDemo.java:585)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: on "new Camera.Area(new Rect(-500, -500, 500,500), 0);" do not place a weight of 0, try 1, or 1000 instead.

Comment: @Brian U Did you check camParams?